# java create objects for view and for edit

Tags: java, architecture

#### problem

I am building my classes, so the owner of the class can edit the information , but another class who just wants to get data from the first class MUST just view the data not edit it.

#### Example

I have class `restaurant` which contains the data of the restaurant like `name`, `offers` , `foods`, the person who has the restaurant can make new object from the restaurant class and edit his information.

The customer can make an object from the restaurant but i want him just to review the data of that restaurant not edit it.

#### what i have tried

- to make the constructor of the restaurant is private but this means neither the restaurant nor the customer can make an object of the restaurant class.
- to make the constructor of the restaurant take the username and the password, in this case the customer won't be able to create a new restaurant object.

What approach should I use to solve my problem? How my classes should be, or what design pattern has to be used?

Any help would be appreciated.

#### Edit

Maybe it is something about design pattern ? I don't know

#### Edit 2

after the first answer, I got this
[image]

Comment: @Alya'aGamal did u read the question ?

Comment: it is not asking about code buddy, i am not asking to give me a code, i am asking to tell me the approach to solve my problem, kinda like how my classes should be, or what design pattern has to be used, I already told you what is the approaches I thought in

Comment: i guessed you need a code so i asked you

Comment: *"what should I do please?"*  Might be better phrased as *"What  approach should I use to solve my problem?  How my classes should be, or what design pattern has to be used?"*  I think this is a 'good question' but for that edit.

Comment: AlexR, would you check the image please

Answer (score 1):

Typical solution for this problem is using 2 interfaces. Let's call them `RestourantDataRetriever` for `read` operations and `RestourantDataAccessor` for read/write operations, e.g.

```
interface RestourantDataRetriever {
    String getName();
    Person getCheif();
    Address getAddress();
}

interface RestourantDataAccessor extends RestourantDataRetriever {
    void setName(String name);
    void setCheif(Person chief);
    Address setAddress(Address address);
}
```

Please pay attention that accessor extends retriever so it can retrieve data too.

Now owner will work with `RestourantDataAccessor` and will have full access to data of restaurant. However other class will work with `RestourantDataRetriever` and will have read only access.

This is not secure solution. You cannot avoid somebody to cast from `RestourantDataRetriever` to `RestourantDataAccessor` and use full functionality. If ytou need secure solution take a look on AspectJ or other similar solutions.

Comment: thanks for your answer. in your solution , should I have `getObject` method to allow the class which inherts it to retreive object from that interface ?,

Comment: I mean in ur way I don't know who to create new object right now, and what should the `customer` class do?

Comment: I added a photo, is that correct? if yes where is the implementation of those interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I created the following example based on the answer of @AlexR, I hope this helps.

Restaurant.java:

```
package org.example;

public interface Restaurant {

    String getName();

    Person getChief();

    Address getAddress();

}
```

RestaurantImpl.java:

```
package org.example;

public class RestaurantImpl implements Restaurant {

    private String name;
    private Person chief;
    private Address address;

    public RestaurantImpl(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person getChief() {
        return chief;
    }

    public void setChief(Person chief) {
        this.chief = chief;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

}
```

RestaurantService.java:

```
package org.example;

public class RestaurantService {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Restaurant restaurant = getRestaurant();

        // only the Getters are available
        String name = restaurant.getName();
        Address address = restaurant.getAddress();
        Person chief = restaurant.getChief();

        // This can not be avoided easily
        if (restaurant instanceof RestaurantImpl) {
            RestaurantImpl modifiableRestaurant = (RestaurantImpl) restaurant;
            modifiableRestaurant.setName(name);
            modifiableRestaurant.setAddress(address);
            modifiableRestaurant.setChief(chief);
        }

    }

    private static Restaurant getRestaurant() {
        RestaurantImpl restaurant = new RestaurantImpl("My Restaurant Name");
        restaurant.setAddress(new Address());
        restaurant.setChief(new Person());
        return restaurant;
    }
}
```